# ReactorDebugAgent.init throw IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jvm, project-reactor

I'm upgrading the app from JVM 8 to 11 and i have any problem. My SpringBootApplication class has ReactorDebugAgent.init();

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
@Import(SwaggerCustomConfig.class)
public class RequisitesApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReactorDebugAgent.init();
        SpringApplication.run(RequisitesApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And when i tried run the app, a catch IllegalStateException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not self-attach to current VM using external process
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.installExternal(ByteBuddyAgent.java:695)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:626)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:606)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:558)
    at reactor.tools.shaded.net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:535)
    at reactor.tools.agent.ReactorDebugAgent.init(ReactorDebugAgent.java:56)
    at ru.gazprombank.omni.pcidss.RequisitesApplication.main(RequisitesApplication.java:23)
```

Well, when i go deeper to stack trace, i found, then this exception is catching in ByteBuddyAgent.class:

```
if ((new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separatorChar + "bin" + File.separatorChar + (System.getProperty("os.name", "").toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains("windows") ? "java.exe" : "java"), "-cp", classPath.toString(), Attacher.class.getName(), externalAttachment.getVirtualMachineType(), processId, quote(agent.getAbsolutePath()), Boolean.toString(isNative), argument == null ? "" : "=" + argument})).start().waitFor() != 0) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not self-attach to current VM using external process");
            }
```

In my Intellij Idea Project settings, Platfirm Settings and Gradle Settings i install and choose 11 version.
Please, help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve it. In @SpringBootApplication class i had ReactorDebugAgent.init();
I dont know, why, but without ReactorDebugAgent it works

Answer (score 0):

you can add -javaagent:reactor-tools.jar